# How to count the number of values in this java program?

Tags: java

This java program generates a random number between 1-6. It also allows the user to choose how many random numbers between 1-6 to generate. I now need to record and output how many instances of each number came up. ie. How many times each number 1,2,3,4,5,6 came up in a single run of the program. How would I go about doing this? Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRandomness {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random generator = new Random();

        System.out.print("How many throws of the dice: ");
        int num = Console.readInt();

        int[] Results = new int[10000];

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

            int d = 1 + generator.nextInt(6);
            System.out.println(d + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd create an array of 6 ints and increment the array entry corresponding to the number picked.

Comment: or 7 to avoid the off by one - and just use counter[result] instead of counter[result-1]

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this hint will help you:

```
int[] counters = new int[6];
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{

}
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey that looks familiar

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That would be a huge memory waste :P

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux but save some -1 and +1 in places.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the random number in d, store it to the Results array "Results[i]"  that way each answer will get stored in the next index of the array.

Then put the print statement in a seperate for loop to print out the results.